# Why I can't see the Crystal Report on my MVC Project?

Tags: model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. After installing Crystal report for visual studio I can't add a new item of type of crystal report. I restarted the visual studio and my PC but I can't see this. I went to control panel and see that Crystal report already installed.

[image: error]

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you describe your problem with more details?

Comment: Try go to control panel and check the programs installed. Look and see if Crystal Report for Visual Studio is there.

Comment: thanks for your reply, in more details I've Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise After installing Crystal report for visual studio I can't add new item of type of crystal report ,I restart the visual studio and my PC but I can't see this.,I go to control panel and see that Crystal report already installed

Comment: i fixed it with 2013 only